# How to generate multiple linear regression with the same skewness and kurtosis of the residuals but different number of observation?

Tags: multiple-regression, simulation

I would like to study the performance of the regression model (parametric and non-parametric). For that matter, i need to simulate the data that have the same skewness and kurtosis of the residuals but in different number of observations (sample size, n). How can i do that in R?

For example, let i need to simulate 3 sets of data (n=10,30, 50) that fulfill the value of skewness and kurtosis 1 and 3 respectively. How to do this?

Thanks you very much in advance for your help..

Comment: If your question is only "how can I do that in R", then it is off topic here & will be closed. You might want to edit this to focus on the statistical question at its core, & deemphasizing R. You might also want to say something about your data, your model, & your goals. At present, it is rather unclear.

Comment: Do you definitely mean to refer to residuals or do you mean to refer to errors? By kurtosis do you mean standardized 4th moment or do you mean excess kurtosis? Are you after specified population values for skewness and kurtosis or specified sample values for skewness and kurtosis? If sample values, using which definitions for sample skewness and kurtosis?